# Way to determine Flex 3 Effect direction?

Tags: apache-flex, effects

Flex Effects include "isPlaying" property to check whether Effect is currently playing or not. But is there a way to find out what is the direction of playback (whether the play was started with playReversedFromEnd)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code; it looks like a playReversed property is added to the EffectInstance of the effect that reflects the playReversedFromEnd property of the play method.

So, you can check that property ( playReversed  ) on the effectInstances returned from the play method.